# Augment custom type in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have broad usage of vertices array like `Vertex[]`
And have many methods performing some actions on such array, like:

```
public doSomethingWith(polygon: Vertex[]) {...}
```

The idea is to create separate type like

```
type Polygon = Array<Vertex>;
```

and incapsulate all the methods there, like:

```
Polygon.prototype.doSomethingWith = () => true;
```

But actually the last line syntax doesn't work.

**Question**:
How can I extend the custom type (like `type Polygon = Array<Vertex>`) with methods (like `Polygon.prototype.doSomethingWith = () => true;`)?

**Update**: I end up with just separate class `Polygons` that contains static methods accepting `Vertex[]` as input parameter. Usage like `Polygons.doSomethingWith(polygon)`;
Let me know if somebody has better ideas.

Answer (score 1):

This seems all wrong so please correct me if I'm not understanding you.

Currently, this is what you have assuming Vertex is just three points.

```
type Vertex = [number, number, number]
type Polygon = Array<Vertex>;
const Poly: Polygon = [[1,2,3], [1,2,3]]
```

A Polygon is just an array of vertices so TypeScript does not see any functions attached to them.

If you want a Polygon to have functions you will need to make it into a class or an object something like this.

```
type Vertex = [number, number, number]

class Polygon {
    vertices: Vertex[] = []
    doSomethingWith () {
        // do something to this.vertices
    }
}
const Poly = new Polygon()
Poly.doSomethingWith()
```

If you want your Polygons to only be an array of vertices and have a separate version have functions. Don't change the Polygon type as it will no longer be true to its structure but instead create a new type.

I think this is ugly as hell but it is fun to see what you can do.

```
type Vertex = [number, number, number]
type Polygon = Array<Vertex>;
type FnPolygon = Polygon & {
    doSomething: () => any
} 

function PolyToFnPoly (poly:Polygon):FnPolygon {
    const fnPoly = pol...
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAahBOwIA8oF4oG0B2BXAtgEYIA0UeRp5Bx8AugFCiRQAKA9gDYgDm726KAEF48AIYgAPHEQoAfAG4m4aADFsHbnwEZNvflABkUAN4MoFqABN2AZXb4IwABYBLbDwBcUABQBKdDkoMWwQBgBfKAYGADNcbABjYFcDPQAVdnU9XzAuEE89bT9PLLztU3NLBP4AZ2AoGI08wVzuYJqoUq1+SotGvQA6G3tHF3ceQX9A0ygAegAqKAARdigRpzcPKHnZqHDeqHgnXHgBfryI6OrsOrY870KDDExMAEYSACYSAGY6MjfPj86IwGNdbl18p0mt0dHduBkIT49H5ohDMAAGOgYxgQoZ2Bwbcb+IA)

[image]

Comment: Yes, I wanted to go second way - not to create separate class wrapper but to extend array. I can simply augment general array with extension methods. But I don't need them for all the arrays. Your second way is nice, but it really looks a bit ugly, especially if to have many extension methods